# How to use callback from within a suspended coroutine flow?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am using coroutines flow and I need to call a suspended emit from within a non-suspended callback. I don't have control over the callback and can't make that interface method suspended. Is it possible to do this?

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.flow

fun foo() = flow {
    someLibraryObject.listenToSomeEvent(object: SomeCallback {
        override fun bar() {
            emit("Some result")
        }
    }
}

interface SomeCallback {
   fun bar()
}
```

Comment: You can use callBackFlow. It's experimental for now. https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html

Comment: Why does your `someLibraryObject.listenToSomeEvent` is not suspended? The main idea behind coroutines is to get rid of callbacks completely! Check if you can make `someLibraryObject.listenToSomeEvent` suspended method and return result from it directly rather than via `SomeCallback`.

Comment: @TayyabMazhar Used callbackFlow and its working as expected. Instead emit using the sendBlocking method.

Comment: @JeelVankhede Don't have control over the interface example SomeCallback.

Comment: @TayyabMazhar You can add it as an answer.

Comment: I agree with @Jeel Vankhede, if you can make your function suspend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**callbackFlow** can be used in this case. Note that it's currently experimental.

```
fun foo() = callbackFlow {
    someLibraryObject.listenToSomeEvent(object: SomeCallback {
        override fun bar() {
             offer("Some result")
        }
    }
}
```

For further details you can refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow#callback)

Comment: I want to update the previous answer of Tayyab Mazhar. since `offer("blabla")` is deprecated, we have to use `trySend("blabla")` instead, so fun foo() = callbackFlow { someLibraryObject.listenToSomeEvent(object: SomeCallback { override fun bar() { trySend("Some result").isSuccess } } }